# Which preposition for "I have no doubt {of/for/about} his ability"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, exam-questions

I had taken a quiz at school, and it was as follows:

**Which one is correct:**

> I have no doubt _____ his ability.
>
> a. of
>
> b. for
>
> c. about

I've chosen "of" but the correct answer was "for".

Was the question meant to assure that he is reliable and there is no need to hesitate to choose him?

So this way, I guess it could also go with "of" and "about," but why really "for"?

That doesn't seem that it could complete the sentence, and the others can't, or is that something grammatically that I should denote?

Comment: ***for*** isn't idiomatic here, so your test is just another very poor quality one (devised by non-native Anglophones, I'm sure). But ***of, about, concerning, regarding, as to*** are all fine (***in*** used to be okay too, but that's rather dated today).

Comment: Of and about are both correct and for is incorrect. Are you sure the question did not begin with "Select the incorrect alternative".

Comment: @Peter , hmm, thanks, I will discuss with tutor about it.